# json tag in .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to generate go structs incl. json tags.

I can do:

```
string name = 1 [json_name="item.name, omitempty"];
```

But that only generates - **json=item.name** and only **json:"name,omitempty"**

```
Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,json=item.name, omitempty,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
```

But I need:- **json:"item.name,omitempty"** Note the tag is missing "item.".
And it looks like no matter what you put in json_name it is not reflected in **"json:"**

Du you know how to set json tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported. The proto file `json_name` is not used to generate the code.
https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/52

I also thought it was a bug
https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/998