# Field name mismatch while deserialising json to golang struct generated from proto

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers

I've a proto like below

```
message HeaderAttributes {
  int32 page_count = 1;
  int32 total_count = 2;
}

message Header {
  HeaderAttributes header_attributes = 1;
}
```

I've generated the struct corresponding to this proto using protoc like below

```
type Header struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    HeaderAttributes *HeaderAttributes `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=header_attributes,json=headerAttributes,proto3" json:"header_attributes,omitempty"`
}

type HeaderAttributes struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    PageCount  int32 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=page_count,json=pageCount,proto3" json:"page_count,omitempty"`
    TotalCount int32 `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=total_count,json=totalCount,proto3" json:"total_count,omitempty"`
}
```

When I try to deserialise below json http response to struct it does not work due to field name mismatch

```
"header": {
        "headerAttributes": {
            "pageCount": 1,
            "totalCount": 1
        }
    }
```

Can someone suggest on how to convert field names in generated struct to be camel case ?

Comment: I've come across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337309/json-tag-in-proto-file where it is said that it's not supported

Comment: Also https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/52 that custom struct tags can't be supported

Answer (score 1):

The JSON-encoded version of your message should not be rooted on `"header"`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    pb "github.com/.../76280593/protos"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

func main() {
    j = []byte(`
{
    "headerAttributes": {
        "pageCount": 1,
        "totalCount": 1
    }
}`)

    message := &pb.Header{}
    if err := protojson.Unmarshal(j, message); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("+%v", m2)
}
```

Succeeds:

```
header_attributes:{page_count:1  total_count:1}
```